# Overloading = operator in C#

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

OK, I know that it's impossible, but it was the best way to formulate the title of the question. The problem is, I'm trying to use my own custom class instead of float (for deterministic simulation) and I want to the syntax to be as close as possible. So, I certainly want to be able to write something like

```
FixedPoint myNumber = 0.5f;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just to make sure: You know that C# already contains a fixed-precision data type called [*decimal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)?

Comment: @Heinzi: `decimal` is still a floating-point type. It just uses 128 bits instead of 32/64 and a decimal exponent instead of a binary one.

Comment: @Joren: Of course, sorry about that, I was trying to be concise. What I meant to write was: "If you are using a custom fixed point data type to avoid the rounding problems usually associated with binary floating-point data-types, you might consider using *decimal* instead, which is able to accurately represent decimal floating-point numbers. If you already considered and rejected that option, please ignore this comment."

Comment: @Heinzi decimal is supposed to be slower than integer math (which my fixed-point essentially is).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, by creating an implicit type cast operator for `FixedPoint` if this class was written by you.

```
class FixedPoint
{
    public static implicit operator FixedPoint(double d)
    {
        return new FixedPoint(d);
    }
}
```

If it's not obvious to the reader/coder that a `double` can be converted to `FixedPoint`, you may also use an explicit type cast instead. You then have to write:

```
FixedPoint fp = (FixedPoint) 3.5;
```

Comment: Care to show an example? Because the documentation clearly say that "=" is not an overloadable operator.

Comment: Well, it won't actually overload the `=` operator, it'll just introduce a cast. If you'd define it as an explicit cast, you'd have: `FixedPoint myNumber = (FixedPoint) 0.5f;`. You'll still have a float at first, but it'll be automatically cast to a FixedPoint. Note that this means you'll still have rounding errors from the floating point representation: you can't actually read the *literal* `0.1f`, you'll still receive a floating point number which best represents the binary repeating number `0.1` as argument to your overloaded method.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras overloading = is impossible, this isn't overloading :)

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras What? That's not what it says.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras - Fero isn't suggesting to overload the `=` operator in a case like this.  What Fero is suggesting is they handle the casting of a FixedPoint to another type.

Comment: golergka said "I certainly want to be able to write something like `FixedPoint myNumber = 0.5f;`" and I just gave an idea how this is possible. :-)

Comment: Thanks! It'll help toward my goal of just finding/replacing stuff in existing float-based code to convert it, so the readability isn't my primary concern though.

Comment: @golergka Cuong Le's answer has a good point as well, It's often very useful to have implicate conversion pairs in out and of the target type.

Comment: You can use `FixedPoint fp = (FixedPoint)3.5m` to start with a decimal literal instead of a float literal if the rounding errors are a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Overload `implicit` cast operator:

```
class FixedPoint
{
    private readonly float _floatField;

    public FixedPoint(float field)
    {
        _floatField = field;
    }

    public static implicit operator FixedPoint(float f)
    {
        return new FixedPoint(f);
    }

    public static implicit  operator float(FixedPoint fp)
    {
        return fp._floatField;
    }
}
```

So you can use:

```
FixedPoint fp = 1;
float f = fp;
```

Comment: The second implicit operator is a great addition, too! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create an implicit type cast.

This is an example:

```
<class> instance = new <class>();

float f = instance; // We want to cast instance to float.

public static implicit operator <Predefined Data type> (<Class> instance)
{
    //implicit cast logic
    return <Predefined Data type>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Implicit is not what you want in = overloading, the other option is to use the explicit operator on your class such as below, which one will cast to it, making it understood by the user:

```
public static explicit operator FixedPoint(float oc)     
{         

     FixedPoint etc = new FixedPoint();          
     etc._myValue = oc;          
     return etc;      
}

... usage

FixedPoint myNumber = (FixedPoint)0.5f;
```